# GRUB can't find an existing file?

Tags: linux, grub, system-installation

I'm trying to install GRUB, but when I try to boot, I get this:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

But that file exists on the drive I'm booting to. Why is it saying "not found" if the file is very clearly there?

I'm using BIOS, and installing everything to sdb1.

Here's my GRUB output:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos3) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdo
s1)
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos1
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ lost+found/ var/ dev/ run/ etc/ tmp/ sys/ proc/ usr/ boot/ home/ lib lib
64 mnt/ opt/ root/ srv/ sbin/ bin/
```

Comment: «trying to install GRUB» — by issuing exactly what command(s)?

Comment: @poige I originally tried `grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdb`, then `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/ --recheck /dev/sdb`, then `grub-install --boot-directory=/boot/ --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sdb`, none worked (I unsuccessfully rebooted the drive I'm installing to, then rebooted the USB with the ISO on it between tries)

Comment: @don_crissti and recent, too. Could it be a problem with the ISO?

Comment: @don_crissti added to question, just one partition and BIOS. I thought it would be extremely straightforward.

Comment: If you have a /boot/ partition, then it may be because there is no /boot on /boot. You can `mount /boot; ln -s . /boot/boot` to fix.

Comment: @don_crissti added to the question. The HDD I'm booting to (/dev/sdb) has nothing to do with DOS, but /dev/sda has a FAT-32 partition for Windows recovery or some nonsense.

Comment: @frostschutz the "missing" file is in `/boot/grub`, what does `/boot/boot` have to do with anything?

Comment: If you have a separate boot partition, then Grub should be looking for paths that DON'T start with /boot/. Grub sees no /boot/ on a boot partition because there isn't one, /boot/ is a path on the root partition only. Mount your boot partition to /mnt/elsewhere/ and you will see there is no /boot/ in the path. The symlink just adds a virtual, optional /boot/ to the path to make both variants work.

Comment: @frostschutz I'm not using a partition for `/boot`. Everything is on `/dev/sdb1`

Comment: @don_crissti I'll do that in a second. I'm not sure `sdb` is `hd0`, I'm thinking GRUB is looking for `/boot` on `/dev/sda`. EDIT, never mind that, I'll have it posted in a second, but it's got a lost+found

Comment: @don_crissti first two run fine, then the third gives me the same `error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.`

Comment: @don_crissti It's on an Inspiron desktop. I'll try those, one second.

Comment: @don_crissti `insmod (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` gave me the original error, and `insmod (hd0,msdos1)/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` gave me `error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/terminal.mod' not found`.

Comment: @don_crissti here's my `grub.cfg`, if it helps: http://pastebin.com/BBgMBKTw

Comment: @don_crissti made it, at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8237/71475

Comment: @don_crissti posted in chat, tried a few more things